# Using a xib file without initializing a view controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'd like to use IB to create a toolbar with assorted toolbar items, but create and use this toolbar programatically - adding it to a view at my discretion, and not while initializing the view controller.

I'm pretty sure it can be done - but haven't been able to find a good reference. Any help?

Comment: Could you give a more contrete example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about NSBundle's `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` method:

```
NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Toolbar" owner:self options:nil];
```

This will return all the objects in nib which you can get using simple array methods. Also note that if nib file references any outlets to other objects in nib - they must be defined in your controller (or any other given nib owner) as well otherwise you'll get KVC exceptions.